# Listen to bluetooth disabled on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, react-native-ios, ios-bluetooth, react-native-ble-manager

I'm creating a Bluetooth application,
and I'm trying to listen to Bluetooth events.

I'm using react-native-bluetooth-classic library:
https://kenjdavidson.com/react-native-bluetooth-classic/api-overview/

I've succeeded listen to `onDeviceRead` from the Bluetooth device on both android and iOS,
but I can't listen to `onStateChanged / onBluetoothEnabled / onBluetoothDisabled` on iOS (but I can on android).

I've tried to create an event listener by myself to listen to these events with `NativeAppEventEmitter` and `DeviceEventEmitter`, but it's still not working for iOS.

```
addEventListener('BLUETOOTH_ENABLED', doSomething);
addEventListener('BLUETOOTH_DISABLED', doSomething);
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: Looking at the source code I don't see anything on the iOS side that emits those events.  The code sets up a `CBCentralManager` instance but doesn't set the delegate for that object to monitor the state; that is how it would receive `.poweredOn` and `.poweredOff` events.  Are you working with an MFi Bluetooth device or a BLE device - this doesn't seem to be the correct package if you want BLE support.

Comment: I'm working with a classic Bluetooth device (not BLE), that's what makes everything a bit more complicated.
should I install another Bluetooth library for the state, and use the react-native-bluetooth-classic for data read + connect?

Comment: Is your device mfi certified?  If not then you are at a dead end on ios.  You can use a BLE Core Bluetooth framework or write your own native code that uses CBCentralManager or submit a PR to the library you are using; it should be pretty simple to add the delegate method and emit the events.